# Material-UI Card Border Color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do you change the border color of card in material-UI?
This doesn't work well below.

```
export default {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      borderColor: `green`,
      borderRadius: 2,
      position: "relative",
      zIndex: 0,
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. If you want to change border color globally you need to use a [theme override](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/).

If you need only for a single card component you can use the `sx` prop as below

```
  <Card sx={{border: '1px solid green', borderRadius: 2}} variant="outlined">Contents</Card>
```

---

For doing this globally use ThemeProvider and pass your custom theme.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiCard: {
      styleOverrides: {
        // Name of the slot
        root: {
          // Some CSS
          borderColor: "green",
          borderRadius: 2,
          position: "relative",
          zIndex: 0,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Use this `theme` in ThemeProvider

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Card>...</Card>
</ThemeProvider>
```

---

Another method is to override the root card class

Example

```
.MuiCard-root {
      borderColor: `green`,
      borderRadius: 2,
      position: "relative",
      zIndex: 0,
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm doing in the global theme just like in my example above. So far its not working.

Comment: @Joseph I have added 2 more methods, please check if it works for you.

Comment: This is what I've been doing but so far none are working :(

Comment: Any errors? Are you importing createTheme like this `import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'`

Comment: Its all good. I've missed something that I didn't post it here. Already accepted your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.

```
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
...

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
      borderColor: "green",
      borderRadius: 2,
      position: "relative",
      zIndex: 0,
  }
});
...

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return <Card className={classes.root}></Card>;
}
```

**Edit:**
For global theme CSS style overrides, you can do this,

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
...
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCard: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
           borderColor: "green",
           borderRadius: 2,
           position: "relative",
           zIndex: 0,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
...

export default function App() {

  return (
       <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Card>green</Card>
       </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

From their doc:

> The theme's styleOverrides key makes it possible to potentially change every single style injected by Material UI into the DOM. This is useful if you want to apply a fully custom design system to Material UI's components.

Comment: I wanted it on the global theme and Im using muiv5

Comment: @Joseph Please check my edited answer.

Comment: This is what I've been doing but so far none are working :(

Comment: do other CSS properties work? if not, can you share more code, as it might be the issue with other code?